# How not to get NAN error in x-text of alpinejs

Tags: alpine.js

Here I want to get the value of the **gap** property, but it shows the NAN error!

```
    <div x-data="tamrin()">
        <h1 x-text="gap"></h1>

        <script>
            function tamrin() {
                return {
                    countTo: new Date("May 30, 2021 00:00:00").getTime(),
                    now: new Date().getTime(),
                    gap: this.countTo - this.now,
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an object literal, so the `this` there refers to the global `window`, not to that object literal.

One option would be to first create the `countTo` and `now` variables and then the object with the `gap` property:

```js
window.MyComponent = function() {
  console.log(`this === window = ${ this === window }`);
  
  const countTo = new Date('May 30, 2021 00:00:00').getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  return {
    countTo,
    now,
    gap: countTo - now,
  };
};
```

```html
<div x-data="MyComponent()">
  <span x-text="gap"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

Another option would be to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and turn `gap` into a [computed property](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-javascript-computed-properties-8f6f096379e3#) so that `this` inside that getter will refer to your component instance:

```js
window.MyComponent = () => ({
  countTo: new Date('May 30, 2021 00:00:00').getTime(),
  now: new Date().getTime(),
  get gap() {
    console.log(`this === window = ${ this === window }`);
    
    return this.countTo - this.now;
  },
});
```

```html
<div x-data="MyComponent()">
  <span x-text="gap"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to continuously refresh the displayed value, use the second solution (getter) and update the `now` property using `setInterval`:

```js
window.MyComponent = () => ({
  countTo: new Date('May 30, 2021 00:00:00').getTime(),
  now: Date.now(),
  
  init() {
    setInterval(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.now = Date.now();
      });
    }, 200);
  },
  
  get gap() {    
    return `${ Math.round(this.countTo - this.now / 1000) } seconds left.`;
  },
});
```

```html
<div x-data="MyComponent()" x-init="init">
  <span x-text="gap"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you both methods work well and another question is: How I can update the property by setInterval():
const now = new Date().getSeconds();
 newseconds: () => {
                        setInterval(() => {
                          return this.now
                        }, 1000)
                    },
<span x-text="newseconds()"></span>
but it doensn't work !